# How to get number of Affected rows from wordpress dbDelta() function

Tags: plugins, php, mysql

I am using dbDalta to import so many row in database.
Now i want to check all row insert successfully, number of affected row and row count which fail to import.

My code:

```
$beginQuery = "INSERT INTO ".$wpdb->prefix."table_name(pzipcode, zip_class, pcity, pstate, lattitude, longitude, pcountry, pstatus, ptime, id) VALUES ";

$zips  = array(
  array('pzipcode' => 'AB10','latitude' => '57.13514','longitude' => '-2.11731','pcity' => 'Aberdeen','pstate' => 'Scotland','pcountry' => 'SCT'),
  array('pzipcode' => 'AB11','latitude' => '57.13875','longitude' => '-2.09089','pcity' => 'Aberdeen','pstate' => 'Scotland','pcountry' => 'SCT'),
// ...................................
// ...................................
);

foreach($zips as $zip) {
     //$beginQuery.' ('.$zip['zp'].',"'.$zip['ct'].'","'.$zip['st'].'","United States",1,"'.current_time('mysql', 1).'")';
    $zipCodeDumper = dbDelta($beginQuery.' ("'.$zip['pzipcode'].'","'.$zip['zip_class'].'","'.$zip['pcity'].'","'.$zip['pstate'].'","'.$zip['lattitude'].'","'.$zip['longitude'].'","'.$zip['pcountry'].'","'.$zip['pstatus'].'","'.$zip['ptime'].'","'.$zip['id'].'")');
    //break;
  }
  if (!$zipCodeDumper) {
    echo "Successfully Imported all Zipcode/postcode.";
  }else{
    echo "Something was wrong!!! Please Try again";
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dbDelta()` is for creating new tables or change the structure (not the data) of existing ones.

You need `$wpdb->insert( $tablename, $zips );` when you want to insert data. Hence the name. :)

And this method returns the number of affected rows, exactly as you need it. If it returns `false`, look at `$wpdb->last_error` to see what exactly went wrong.